# Search text files and display results with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, search

I have a folder (`blogfiles/posts`)  with various text files, numbered (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...) and they each hold a post for a blog (I haven't learned SQL yet). I'm trying to make a search engine for it that will take a query from a text box (done with this part), then search the files for each word in the query, and return the results (possibly in order of the number of times the word occurs).

Each text file looks like this:

> Title on Line 1
>
> Date Posted on Line 2 (in Month Date, Year form)
>
> Post body to search on lines 3 and up

I currently have this code:

```
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];
$qArray = explode(" ", $q);

//preparing files
$post_directory = "blogfiles/posts/";
$files = scandir($post_directory, 1);
$post_count = (count($files)) - 2;
$files = array_pop($files); // there are 2 server files I want to ignore (#1)
    $files = array_pop($files); // there are 2 server files I want to ignore (#2)

foreach ($files as $file) {
    //getting title
        $post_path = $post_directory . $file;
    $post_filecontents = file($post_path);
    $post_title = $post_filecontents[0];
    echo "<tr><td><a href=\"blog?p=" . $file . "\">" . $post_title . "</a></td></tr>";
}

if ($post_count > 2) {
$postPlural = "s";
}

echo "<tr><td>" . $post_count . " post" . $postPlural . ".";
?>
```

I'll apologize now for the formatting, I was trying to separate it to troubleshoot.
Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (Sidenote) *"I haven't learned SQL yet"* - Do. You'll thank me for it. The maintenance using SQL is a fraction of what you're using now.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just haven't had time to devote to it. I learned PHP in under a week, but I just can't understand SQL commands as easily.

Comment: I'm working out an SQL approach. I set up a database, just have to move everything over. Good thing this isn't high-priority, I'll have time to work on it. I just learned PHP last month, so SQL was eventually going to happen. I think the comments have gotten a bit sidetracked, yes? ;)

Comment: I've now moved everything over into my database, and I have rewritten my code to fetch posts. It's working so far, now I just need to rewrite the search page.

Comment: Hit another snag with mysqli. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24480864/3658574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to search files.

1. use preg_match_all function to match pattern for each file.
2. use system() function to run external command like grep (only available under *nix).
3. use strpos function ( not recommended because of low performance and lack of support of pattern ).
4. If you will face a big traffic you'd better use pre-build indexes to accelerate the search. for example split the posts into tokens ( words ) and add position info along with the words, when user search the some words you can just split the words first and then look for the indexes. It's simpler to discribe this method than to implement it. You may need a existing full-text search engine like Apache Lucene.