# Search mysqli for multiple values in one column, return matching another, sort by count of occurrences?

Tags: php, arrays, search, mysqli

Before I start, here is the sample format of the database:

```
id  date         title            content
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   YYYY-MM-DD   some text here   lots of stuff to search here
2   YYYY-MM-DD   some text here   lots of stuff to search here
3   YYYY-MM-DD   some text here   lots of stuff to search here
```

I currently have something set up to get the id of a row, then assign the date, title, and content to PHP variables to display in different places on a page (it's a blog, these are posts).

Now I'm trying to make a function that will search the content for each string in an array (the code already splits words entered into the search box by spaces into an array, so entering `cat hotdog suit` will give `[0]cat [1]hotdog [2]suit`).

I have a loop set up that performs a query on each of the strings:

```
foreach ($queryArray as $queryArrayString) {
    // query the content column for $queryArrayString
}
```

However, I can't figure out what query I should use to find the id of the post that the string occurs in. I'd like to assign it to a variable (`$results`).
After reversing the array, so higher ids (newer results) show up first, I'd like to find the titles of each id and store it like this:

```
id (let's say it is 3) => matching title
id (let's say it is 1) => matching title
```

Is this possible? I've tried several different queries, and none worked, but one took 2 minutes and loads of memory to attempt.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've created a text index of the title and content columns (I'd like to search both), shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWPJW.png).

Is it possible to search this? Like I've said in the comments, I'd just need it to return the corresponding id and title somehow. (Title for result link text, id for link destination: `<a href="blog?p=[id]">[title]</a>` is the format I'm using

Comment: You could use MySQL `LIKE` conditions: `SELECT * From your_posts WHERE content LIKE '%firstword%' AND content LIKE '%secondword%'` etc

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement full-text searching in your table. Read the MySQL documentation on it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Otherwise, searching lots of text with `LIKE` will be very slow.

Comment: I have my indexes set up like [this](http://i.imgur.com/bTwnwkx.png). Is this the best way to go? Is it possible to search the `text` index because that would search both titles and content? Then I'd just need it to return the corresponding id and title somehow. (Title for result link text, id for link destination: `<a href="blog?p=[id]">[title]</a>` is the format I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ideal world, there are complex solutions available like Apache SOLR or Elasticsearch for indexing records and return efficiently when multiple text-search-terms are provided. Luckily, you can achieve such results by trying something like this (not tested)..

```
$searchTerms = "cat hotdog suit";
$searchArray = explode(' ',$searchTerms);

$conditions = array();
$foreach (searchArray as $searchTerm){
    $conditions[] = 'title-content LIKE %'.searchTerm.'%';
}

$query = '
SELECT
    tableName.id,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', tableName.title,tableName.content) as title-content
FROM
    tableName
WHERE
    '.implode(' OR ', $conditions);
```

Comment: Okay, I've put this in (slightly modified), and I'm not sure how to get the results out of it. Here's my complete code: [pastebin.com/7cD9yaFm](http://pastebin.com/7cD9yaFm) Note that `$q` is defined at the start of the document with `<?php $q = $_GET["q"]; ?>` because it is used elsewhere.

Comment: Where did you execute the query?

Comment: And that's why I can't code with 2 hours of sleep. I've added `$results = mysqli_query($databaseConnect, $query);` but `$results` will not echo. I was expecting to get `Array`, but it did nothing.

Comment: The link you shared still has "tableName" as the name of the table inside query (and no execution). I'd echo the query and try to run it on phpmyadmin to find out if there's any error.

Comment: Here is my entire code now: http://pastebin.com/175Ektcz
I ran it in phpmyadmin and got this: http://pastebin.com/vnMZJjNz
I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Think you should take a short break and possibly have some sleep ;). I am sure once you get up and read this message thread while having a nice cuppa tea/coffee, the solution will likely be obvious.

Comment: I redid it completely where each word is fed to each post and it echoes a table row if it is found. It isn't too slow, and doesn't consume too much memory. You can try it here: robiotic.net/blogsearch?q=google and I'll post the code when I have time later.

Comment: Here is my final code: pastebin.com/00xwZVwL [pastebin.com/00xwZVwL](http://pastebin.com/00xwZVwL)

Note that the `if ($fail == false)` is set at the top of the page to detect blank searches.